# Getting nth-child to work with an added class

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am having trouble figuring out why my `nth-child(even)` is not working with my added class.

Basically, I am wanting to style the even elements different from the original. Both 'Style 1' and 'Style 2' are two different variations I have tried. Neither are working.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Original:

```
.catalogSmallCircle.rectangle {
    width: 400px;
    min-height: 200px;
    webkit-transition: all 1s; transition: all 1s;transform: translate(-30%, 
-45%);-webkit-transform: translate(-30%, -45%);
 }
```

New:

Style 1

```
.rectangle .catalogSmallCircle:nth-child(even) {
    webkit-transition: all 1s; transition: all 1s;transform: translate(-80%, -45%);-webkit-transform: translate(-80%, -45%);
    background: green;
}
```

Style 2

```
.catalogSmallCircle:nth-child(even).rectangle {
    webkit-transition: all 1s; transition: all 1s;transform: translate(-80%, -45%);-webkit-transform: translate(-80%, -45%);
    background: green;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="smallCatalogButtonWrap">
    <div class="catalogSmallCircle">
      <div class="catalogSmallCircleIn">
        <div class="total-center">
           <div class="circlePlus"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="catalogCircleExpand">
        <div class="catalogExpandClose"></div>
        <div class="total-center expandText">
           <span class="catalogName pdfSubHeader"></span>
            <p class="dGw circleExpandText"></p>
            <button class="catalogDownload downloadButton" >View</button>
            <button class="catalogDownload requestButton" >Request</button> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.catalogSmallCircleIn').on('click', function(event) {
    var $smallCircle = $(this).closest('.catalogSmallCircle');

    $smallCircle
        .addClass('rectangle')
        .find('.catalogSmallCircleIn')
        .hide();

    $smallCircle
        .find('.catalogCircleExpand')
        .fadeIn(100)
        .addClass('rectangle');
```

Comment: share the html that goes with (but it seems you have extra space on style 1)

Comment: @TemaniAfif HTML Added.

Comment: there  is no `rectangle` in your html

Comment: @TemaniAfif I add the rectangle class via JS. I didn't want to over complicate my question, so I dumbed it down quite a bit.

Comment: you need to post the complete code so we can verify, if the class is added by JS then JS is needed also

Comment: so try to create a working code where we can test with the JS and clearly see the issue